# Spawn Child process in XP with Perl

Tags: perl, process, windows-xp

I would like to spawn a child process in XP; for example:

```
system "start", "cmd.exe", "perl", "child.pl", "arg1";
```

When I run this, it tells me that "start doesn't exist." (Start works in Win 7).

When I run:

```
system "cmd.exe", "perl", "child.pl", "arg1";
```

The child process occurs in the same console as the parent process and upon completion the console session ends--so, I believe that the child simply takes over and the parent dies.

Normally, when I run these commands in Win 7, a new console appears and everything works fine.

When I type:

```
"start"
```

into the XP console, a new console appears--why can it find it then, but not when I call it from within a Perl script???

I've tried `Win::Process` and `Win::Job` to no avail: it still just kills the parent and starts the child, the whole tree dying upon completion.

Banging my head against this. Does anyone have a sure fire way to create an independent child process *in XP* (and not with `fork`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start is a built-in in cmd.exe, try `system('cmd.exe /c "start perl child.pl arg1"')`.

Comment: It did start a new process! however, the child dies immediately and then console reverts back to `Z:\>`. When I ctrl-c, it says `child died with signal 2, without coredump`. When I run an identical command `start perl child.pl arg1` manually through the console, everything works fine.